# How to create and retrieve a cookie in Moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to create a custom cookie in moodle using the following function:

```
setcookie('testcookie', "", time() - 3600, '/', 'localhost');
```

I cannot see any cookie created from my browser inspector. I am looking to create a cookie under current development directory, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a value and the time should be in the future.

eg:

```
setcookie('testcookie', "testcookievalue", time() + 3600);
```

UPDATE:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['testcookie'])) {
    $value = clean_param($_COOKIE['testcookie'], PARAM_TEXT);
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Hi russel, I would also like to know, how I would be able to retrieve the value of the cookie I have set using setcookie()?

Comment: Is there any way to update the content of the cookie rather than recreating it everytime? I want to create a cookie with a certain lifetime, and then I want to update its content/value without altering its lifetime. How is that possible?